# Not able to import module from DLL using python

Tags: c#, python, .net, dll, python.net

I am trying to import IEDExplorer(open source) methods which is developed using c#.Net. I created IEDExplorer.dll for 0x64 bit architecture on Visual Studio 2015 and trying to use generated IEDExplorer.dll from python. My code is as below:

```
import clr, sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\WORK\IEC61850\Iedexplorer\bin\x64\Debug")
clr.AddReference("IEDExplorer")
import IEDExplorer
```

When tried to import IEDExplorer module it is giving as "ImportError: No module named 'IEDExplorer". Can anybody please help on this.

Comment: are you using pythonnet or ironpython?

Comment: I am using pythonnet

Comment: Where did you the source for IEDExplorer?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/iedexplorer/code/ci/master/tree/

Comment: I could able to solve this after so much trial. Thanks..

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: I placed the DLL file where python is installed. Then it started working.

Comment: it would be nice if you added your solution as an answer.